# How do I load a non-reentrant C++/CLI DLL twice in C#?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, reentrancy

I'm attempting to load a C++/CLI DLL into my C# program. The DLL exposes its main class as a singleton because it contains C code with a lot of global variables. So, unfortunately, the DLL is non-reentrant. The DLL can connect to a single instance of a piece of hardware (identified by a hardware ID).

However, I have multiple pieces of the same hardware attached, and I'd like to load multiple instances of the DLL into my C# program so I can access each piece of hardware.

Is it possible, in C#, to load that C++/CLI DLL multiple times into different memory spaces so that the globals in the DLL don't conflict with each other?

Let's assume for the purposes of this question that I don't have access to the source code of the C++/CLI DLL.

Comment: Can't you build the DLL multiple times, with different names, for each piece of hardware?

Comment: @sturcotte06 Yes. I can build it, let's say--3 times. And then someone will come along and attach 4 of these USB dongles. Where do I stop?

Comment: You can't load the same DLL multiple times. You can copy it under a different name so it's a "different" DLL, or you can farm off work to child processes that you communicate with through an IPC mechanism of your choice. The latter is probably more stable, as the DLL wasn't designed to load more than once and it might create or rely on global kernel objects that get the same name -- there's no working around that.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert. Does loading the DLL into different Application Domains (if that even makes sense) effectively put it in different processes?

Comment: Produce 8 DLLs so you can support 8 USB ports. Expose the limitation. That's why globals are bad; you want clear scope so you can have any numbers of scopes at runtime. Bad design gives bad results.

Comment: @watkipet A DLL is only a dynamically linked library; it links at runtime instead of compile time. It was not meant to manage object lifetime, but to load features dynamically. The one who made the DLL used the library as a lifetime. You can only link this DLL once per process. There's no notion of application domain is operating systems; it's purely a usermode invention of microsoft.

Comment: @sturcotte06 To make multiple copies of a managed DLL that don't collide, I'll need to change the name, the namespace, and the assembly GUID, right? Can you post an answer showing how my C# program can do this for an existing assembly DLL for which I don't have the source?

Comment: While AppDomains do offer some form of separation (less so than processes) whether or not your assembly would work with that is an open question. The unmanaged parts (i.e. the code that the C++/CLI is wrapping) do not know or care about AppDomains and will not be isolated by them -- and moreover, all this is still running in the same process. All instances would share the same C runtime heap and the same kernel handles. There are many ways such a setup can fail.

Comment: Anyone care to put this info into an answer? Something that mentions AppDomains (and why they wouldn't work in this scenario), IPC (doesn't have to go into implementation details), and copying / modifying the DLL (without having access to the source) would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by loading same dll twice to RAM, but you will need to use different virtual .dll filename for each time.

See following project as example:

https://github.com/tapika/dllloader

`test_managed_dllloader`-project.

Comment: Does this load the DLL's variables into an entirely separate memory space? i.e. does this comment still hold? `All instances would share the same C runtime heap and the same kernel handles. There are many ways such a setup can fail.`

Comment: If you copy same dll to different dll filename and load it - they will get different set of globals. I guess it's not necessary to load them additionally into ram.

Comment: See also https://github.com/tapika/dllloader/issues/1#issuecomment-1279689837